# jQuery - put html in array for ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to put some HTML in an array for an ajax query, but when I see array in console then there is only first line of the html. why ? is there a proper way to do this?

**My code**

```
    var data = new Array();
        $('.get_html').each(function() {
            var html = $(this).html();
            data.push(html);                
        });
   console.log(data);
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle?

Comment: Yeah it looks like you want to log data instead of content.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YMaSJ/1/

Comment: this can be easily rewritten as `var data = $('.get_html').map(function () {
    return $(this).html();//return this.innerHTML
}).get();`  see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YMaSJ/2/

Comment: console.log(content);change in console.log(data);

Comment: @ArunPJohny it was writing mistake, data = content

Comment: @ArunPJohny wow now its working, when i added get()

Comment: @user007 I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `data` instead of `content`, Also you can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map) to do this

```
var data = $('.get_html').map(function () {
    return $(this).html();//return this.innerHTML
}).get();
console.log(data);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YMaSJ/)

Answer (score 2):

You're logging the variable **content** instead of the **data** array you're pushing html too.

```
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change variable `content` to `data` in console.log

```
var data = new Array();
    $('.get_html').each(function() {
        var html = $(this).html();
        data.push(html);                
    });
console.log(data);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ujMwm/)